# Automatically name current version when Google Sheets is opened

Tags: google-sheets, keyboard-shortcuts, version-control, google-sheets-macro

I'd like to automatically maintain the original version of a Google Sheets file whenever the file is opened.  Manually, this would involve simply opening the file and selecting File/Version History/Name Current Version.  But recording a macro of these actions doesn't capture these action.

Alternately, on Google Drive, looking at the versions shows when the file was changed but doesn't allow me to roll back to an older version.

Suggestions appreciated.

Comment: I'm downvoting this because the feature for rolling back the document to a previous version exists. The original version is thus in the version history. As user0 says, you need to click on "See version history".

Answer (score 0):

You could map this keyboard shortcut: <kbd>**`LEFT ALT`**</kbd> + <kbd>**`F`**</kbd> + <kbd>**`H`**</kbd> + <kbd>**`N`**</kbd> and <kbd>**`ENTER`**</kbd> which does what you want. And as platform you could use **[AHKscript](https://www.autohotkey.com/)**.

To actually rollback you will need to go here:

[image: 0]